# Getting keys and values from a list on a JSON String using BasicDBObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb, list

I have a `String` with a JSON that contains a list. Its something like this:

```
{
    "counts":[
        {"foo827138": 123124, "bar2918":312312, "something_else321-313":2321321},
        {"foo1231412": 4321, "bar1231515":123, "something_else3012931":7282},
        {"foo1210820": 1234, "bar10293810":3112, "something_else12094":1321}
    ]
}
```

After parsing it with `BasicDBObject.parse()`:

```
DBObject doc = BasicDBObject.parse(jsonString);
```

How can I get the keys and values on `counts` list?

PS.: `doc.get("counts")` returns a `BasicDBList` object. I can only iterate over this with:

```
for (Object a : doc) {
    // Something
}
```

`Object` does not provide a `get()` method or something like. So I don't know how to get any of my key names and respective values.

Comment: when you reference `BasicDBObject` are you talking about the MongoDB instance of it? can you provide the code where you are calling parse()?

Comment: Yes, it is a MongoDB instance of it. I've edited the question providing the exact scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document document = Document.parse(jsonString);
List<Document> countsArray = document.get("counts",List.class);
for (Document doc : countsArray){
    doc.keySet(); //keys
    doc.values(); //values
    for (Map.Entry entry : doc.entrySet()){
        // iterate over each pair
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried yourObject.get("keyname")

Comment: The keys are randomic